# Font color tag not working

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to echo some text with color red using php. The code I have given is

```
<?php if($_SESSION['phone_error']==1) {
                echo '<font color="red">Please Enter a valid phone number</font>';
                } ?>
```

Can someone please tell me why this is not working?

Comment: You're about 20 years late.

Comment: Not working you mean you have text but with color other than red? Or you don't see any text? Please be more clear.

Comment: Have you look your css? Perhaps there exists an "!important" rule the overwrite yours

Comment: @BoltClock it's [still working](http://jsfiddle.net/wbAu4/) after all those years so guess it's still supported for a reason. :)

Comment: Seems like $_SESSION['phone_error'] IS NOT EQUAL TO 1 (or your sessions don't work at all - I don't find session_start() in this code snipplet)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: Yes, it's for the people who are late.

Comment: Check out first what you have in the HTML document as sent to a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tag is not more available in HTML5, you should learn some basic HTML and CSS.

```
<?php if($_SESSION['phone_error']==1) {
  echo '<span style="color:red;">Please Enter a valid phone number</span>';
} ?>
```

Comment: 1) Doesn't mean browsers will stop supporting it. 2) How do you know he's using HTML5?

Comment: My point is just to tell him this tag should no more be used - it's like using <marquee> to me. We are in 2012, if I can remove a <font> tag from the web I'm happy with it :)

Comment: I am not using html 5. Anyway updated my code with span, so damien, you should be happy as you are successful in removing a <font> tag from the web. btw thanks man! ;D

Comment: If the change helped, then you changed something else, too, when making the change. A styled `span` element does not work more widely than `font` (actually, less). Besides, as this is apparently an error message, `strong` would be more logical than `span`.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
echo '<span style="color:red;">Please Enter a valid phone number</span>';
```